# Where does Time Machine store its settings?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I'm looking for the file that contains all the Time Machine exclusions entered in its `Options` dialogue. I know that (some of?) the scheduling related settings are stored in the `com.apple.backupd-*.plist` files at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` but I haven't been able to find the exclusions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On Lion, what files are excluded by rule from a Time Machine backup?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-lion-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup) - The time machine exclusions are implemented in a way slightly more complicated than one list.

Comment: No, it isn't a dupe as "Time Machine exclusions entered in its Options dialogue" refers to the exclusions entered by the user. Helpful link nonetheless...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is in the root directory of the actual backup e.g. `/Volumes/Back3/Backups.backupdb/flat/Latest/.exclusions.plist` for a machine called flat but that only shows what happened.

More usefully - if you want to edit things see `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`

I got the informatiuon from this [blog](http://earthlingsoft.net/ssp/blog/2008/03/x5_time_machine)

Comment: Cool question and answer. Have you tried to edit that file, and if so, what happened?

Comment: On a fresh OS X Lion installation: moved com.apple.TimeMachine.plist and com.apple.TimeMachine.plist.lockfile then copied com.apple.TimeMachine.plist from a system backup (Snow Leopard). Then enabled and configured TimeMachine. Bingo!

Comment: @David DelMonte, me I didn't dare to edit the file.

Comment: It is a strange thing, but on my Maverick `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` looks like binary file. How could I edit it?

Comment: @AntonEgorov that is a separate question - ask how to edit a binary plist file (Apple's default is now binary I think)

Answer (score 10):

The list of folders in System Preferences is stored in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`.

`/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist` contains folders that are excluded by default.

`sudo mdfind com_apple_backup_excludeItem==com.apple.backupd` searches for files with a `com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem` extended attribute.

`tmutil addexclusion` adds an extended attribute. `sudo tmutil addexclusion -p` adds the path to `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`.

Answer (score 3):

Protip:  (ugh) If you want to find the corresponding preference file on the file system for a system preference or application preference setting, I use this trick:

I makeup a word that would never possibly exist on my system (usually horrible offensive)
something like "ShittleCheezeman"

Then I edit the preference that I want to track down and write that word into one of the preference settings that accepts a string or phrase and save the preference setting.

Then, right after that; I run something like:

`sudo find / -name "*.plist" -mmin -10 -exec grep -l "ShittleCheezeman" {} \;`

That will search every plist file on the whole system that has been modified in the last 10 minutes and list the one that contains the unique phrase.  Or you might be able to use spotlight though I find it to be an unreliable software as most database-backed desktop apps tend to be

Comment: Does this find the text in binary plists?

Comment: If you do `-exec plutil -convert xml1 && grep -l "Phrase" {} \;` it will convert the file to an XML plist first.  You could also look into using  `PlistBuddy -c Print`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plutil` or `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to view and modify the `plist` file where the paths are stored:

```
plutil -extract SkipPaths xml1 -o - /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist
```

or

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print SkipPaths' /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist
```