# In Mountain Lion, where is the exclude list for Time Machine stored?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

I want to know if the list of Time Machine excluded files (pictured below) can be found in a file somewhere.

[image: Time Machine exclude list]

I know about the question [On Lion, what files are excluded by rule from a Time Machine backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-lion-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup) which has a lot of good information about `StdExclusions.plist`, `mdfind` and `tmutil` – but not the answer for this question.

[One answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69214/2461) also talks about `.exclusions.plist`, which is almost the answer to this question. But there's a catch, I haven't done a backup yet, so I can't read the `.exclusions.plist` file from the Time Machine backup volume.

I'm doing `cd / ; sudo find . -iname "*exclusions*"` now, keeping my fingers crossed.

Answer (score 3):

The Mountain Lion settings are identical to the Lion settings as described here:

- [Where does Time Machine store its settings?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33494/where-does-time-machine-store-its-settings?rq=1)

The answer is `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist`

Comment: This was the key answer, since

`defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist ExcludeByPath`

does what tmutil listexclusions should have done

Comment: In Mojave `defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist SkipPaths`