# iCloud settings on Mac book shows that Dropbox is storing its file inside iCloud when that isn't actually happening

Tags: icloud, settings, dropbox

I was running through my settings when i stumbled upon this. I'm curious what is actually stored inside iCloud (by Dropbox), because the files inside Dropbox are obviously not (my Dropbox folder is much bigger than iCloud capacity)

[image: iCloud settings]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V9jt.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely it's not the data you put on dropbox cloud. I think [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/129107) old answer hints about your question. I know what time machine back up is but I think this service might later be included in iCloud backups too.

As for iOS, [ios backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428)
details explain what it stores.