# OS X Mavericks system restore from external drive using Time Machine

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, partition, restore

I have a 3TB Seagate USB external drive (MBR scheme), divided in 2 primary partitions: one of ~500 GB has been created and formatted on Windows using Paragon Partition Manager with HSF+.

I did a full system backup using Time Machine to this partition (apparently, successfully - or so I thought). (Directly, not as an image.)

When I try to follow this tutorial: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14185 , as soon as I press Command R, I get thrown into an Internet Recovery, which takes about an hour to complete. I might be wrong, but, according to some research I've done, this should be the behavior when I don't have a dedicated recovery partition? If so - I don't see the point in creating the full system backup if I cannot readily make use of it.

After said hour passes, I am presented with the options that should have readily been available to begin with, and I am able to do a system restore from the `Time Machine`.

Said restore, though, ends after a while in (what should have been?) a boot screen: I get the spinning wheel but the Apple logo is switched for a "crossed O" as in, the "Access denined" symbol.

How could I prevent the Internet Recovery to take place, go directly to perform a Time Machine recovery? Any suggestions about the second issue, might they be connected somehow?

Comment: As an aside: Time Machine is primarily focused on backing up user data on a drive. It purposely omits data that can be gotten back from the OS installation media. See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115024/292 for more details on exclusions. A full recovery necessarily involves laying down a clean OS and then overlaying the latest changes by using the Time Machine backup. That's why you're getting sent to the Internet Recovery phase.

Comment: Thank you, Ian. Following Apple's recommendation for a "full system backup/recovery using Time Machine" (during backup, I didn't exclude anything as far as the OS folders/files go), even though there are the files that are on purpose excluded in the background, I would expect to be able to get my system back in quite a "similar" state. (I am doing some "experimental" development, and I'm looking to get the system as close "back" as possible. I'm also looking into SuperDuper!, as an alternative, once I manage to get forwarded anywhere else than to "Internet Recovery"). Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly related to partitioning on a Windows machine.
You can verify this by using Disk Utility to look at the Drive, in particular the `Partition Map Scheme`. This needs to be `GUID Partition Table` but is probably MBR.

You would need to repartition on OS X, but this will need you to erase all data.

Comment: That might very well be the case. Let me check this and get back with the results. In the mean time, thank you for taking to to share this!

Comment: would I be facing the same issue if I were to backup, again, to the MBR-partitioned drive, but an image of the OS X instead of directly to the drive?