# Where do applications store local settings?

Tags: time-machine, preferences, data-recovery, skype

Where does OS X store local settings for applications such as license keys, Skype favorite contacts, etc.

Yesterday I was troubleshooting an issue with an Apple rep and he had me delete a bunch of files and folders, one of which includes ~/library/caches/*  I can't remember the rest though.  Later I noticed NONE of my programs would launch because they required license keys to be input.  All of my EyeTV scheduled recordings were gone. Dock preferences were reset. It's been a nightmare.

If I can get the location of these files, I can just recover them from Time Machine.

Comment: Restore your ~/Library folder ?

Answer (score 3):

Applications store their data in any or all of the following locations:

```
 ~/<individual application folders>
 ~/Documents/<individual application folders>
 ~/Library/<individual application folders>
 ~/Library/Caches/*/<individual application folders>
 ~/Library/Preferences/*/<individual application folders>
 ~/Library/Application\ Support/<individual application folders>
 /Library/<individual application folders>
 /Library/Caches/*/<individual application folders>
 /Library/Preferences/*/<individual application folders>
 /Library/Application\ Support/<individual application folders>
 /private/tmp/<esoterically named folders>
 /private/var/tmp/*/<esoterically named folders>
 /private/var/db/receipts/
```

Also, it is not unheard of for an application to store data within its own application folder structure.

---

Please note that Time Machine does [not backup everything](http://pondini.org/TM/11.html). It will automatically exclude such things as iOS device backups among other items such as caches, logs, and what's in the Trash. You can view [what is excluded](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-lion-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup) by Time Machine automatically with this command:

```
 cat /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist
```

Comment: Don't forget ~/Library/Containers/ for sandboxed apps :)

Comment: nice catch... no need to edit, want *you* to get credit!