# Excluding Chrome's session storage from Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, google-chrome

Is it advisable to exclude `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Session\ Storage/` from Time Machine backups? It certainly sounds like a prime candidate, but I am unable to find confirmation anywhere, which surprises me given that Chrome is fairly widely used.

Comment: What's the reason you're looking at excluding this?

Comment: @MK - I'm looking at excluding this so that it doesn't occupy a bunch of space on my Time Machine drive. [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/) tells me that the contents of the folder have been changing a lot, though to be fair the total size of the folder is fairly small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're concerned about this occupying space unnecessarily, you could the exclude the folder. While you're at it, you could exclude the following folders since the rest (apart from `Session Storage`) are not useful to backup repeatedly/regularly either:

> ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Session Storage
>   ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage
>   ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Application Cache

In more recent versions of Chrome/OS X, these folders may be located in:

/Users/$USER/Library/Caches/Google/

Note that excluding `Session Storage` will prevent your sessions from being backed up - so you cannot restore back to older sessions from a backup.
Excluding `Local Storage` will prevent restoring the storage used by some/many web sites that use local storage to store information (to support offline use or for longer term identification).

Comment: Thanks @MK. Just to be clear, there are three folders total that one might exclude here: Session Storage; Local Storage; and Application Cache--right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You could exclude these three folders.

Comment: In more recent versions of Chrome/OS X, these folders may be located in

`~Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Google/`

Comment: And it looks to me from `/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist` like `~/Library/Caches` is excluded from Time Machine backups by default.

Comment: @kuzzooroo -- that file does not appear to exist on Big Sur 11.6.2 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-os-x-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup#comment629536_25833