# License Keys not Transferred in Time Machine Restore

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore, license

I have just restored a Time Machine backup to a new disk, and I am finding that I need to re-enter scores of licenses for specific applications (while others seem to be retained without issue). Specifically, I am using RapidWeaver, and most of the Stacks require license keys. They must be stored somewhere, but I have yet to be able to determine the location. I would like to restore that directory from a backup to avoid countless hours of data re-entry.

Can someone point out where this information is stored? It doesn't have to be specific to RapidWeaver, even though that would be helpful. I just want to know where to look to be able to restore my previous keys, in order to save a bit of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the files I want are stored in `\~Library\Preferences` under each stack's specific plist file. I don't quite understand why none of them transferred over from the original backup, but I am hopeful they will copy over when I visit the Time Machine backup.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in list of exclusions stored in `/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist`.

Also, apps can use a file's metadata to exclude it from backups. You can view this list of files by running the command:

`sudo mdfind "com_apple_backup_excludeItem = 'com.apple.backupd'"`

This works by changing the extended attribute `com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem`.

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/25833/320223