# add /home to time machine backup list

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

I would like to backup the /home directory on a macbook pro running osx 10.8.5 using time machine, unfortunately this is directory is ignored by default. According to this post:

[On OS X, what files are excluded by rule from a Time Machine backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-os-x-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup)

the file:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist
```

stores the list of built in exclusions where the /home path is under paths that are excluded. Can I delete the line that contains the /home directory in order to add it to the list of directories that time machine will back up? What are some unintended consequences that I might run into by doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this. OS X uses /Users/(username) instead. /home is there for compatibility.

This [Apple Support Document](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18923?locale=en_US) describes how Mac OS X handles multiple users.

> Your home folder isn’t actually named “Home.” It’s named with your user name. If your Mac has several users set up, each user has a home folder.

Comment: So the computer was changed using the solution described here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362703/how-can-i-use-the-home-directory-on-mac-os-x

so that the home directory could be used. Since files are now stored in /home, I would like to have it automatically backup