# Restoring Catalina timemachine back-up to Mojave

Tags: backup, time-machine, mojave, catalina

I have read a few posts and answer but I am not quite sure...

I was on Catalina and for multiple compatibility reasons, I need to go back on Mojave. I did a time machine back up on Catalina, erased the startup disk and Mojave (which my Mac was shipped with) is now installing. What is going to happen when I restore from my Catalina time machine backup?

I don't want the OS restored. I want everything I had on Catalina switched to Mojave.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the system software installed, time machine will install your personal files and the files you select. It will not install the system software.

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328624/does-time-machine-restore-whole-system) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I confirm, everything went all fine!