# My Time Machine is backing up in /private/var/folders/

Tags: backup, time-machine

My MacBook Pro (10.15.7) is backing up parts of the drive I didn't expect. I have been cleaning up and excluding directories, but this time I found something I thought was excluded by default:
private/var/folders.

To examine I have been using 'Timedog'. Here is a piece of today's output:
[image: Timedogoutput1]

Again, as far as I know and as referenced [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-os-x-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup), the standard exclusions

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist
```

include ('exclude') private/var/folders/ under the "contents excluded" category, meaning that the folder container is backed up but nothing inside. Clearly here we have 42.6 MiB of content.

Comment: The StdExclusions file doesn't exist in macOS 11 - not at that location.  Does it exist in Catalina?  Anyway, if I look in the Time Machine volumes, the .exclusions.plist (in the root of each backup) does include /private/var/folders as excluded.  But a subset of the content is in my TM backups - a few tens of MB. Hmm!

Comment: Can it be possible the /private/var/folders data was already there? When was it created?

Comment: @CousinCocaine what are you implying? Do backups of excluded items continue if they were ever backed up?

Comment: @RichardBirkett, what I meant was that the files were put there once (first backup run?), and thereafter never touched again. Thats why I was curious when the files where created or last touched.

Answer (score 3):

This is an attempt at a (partial) answer. It is too long for a comment.

Apple makes changes (mostly minor) to Time Machine without notification or  documentation. I believe that the question and answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-os-x-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup) are too old to be reliable for recent versions of macOS.

The StdExclusions.plist does not exist inside the backupd.bundle on macOS 11, so that is no longer a mechanism for exclusion.  I don't know if it exists in macOS 10.15.7. And even if it does exist, whether it is used.

[Mike Bombich](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/some-files-and-folders-are-automatically-excluded-from-backup-task) of Carbon Copy Cloner specifies what is excluded by CCC and says that it excludes only part of /private/var/folders.  He lists these as being excluded:

- /private/var/folders/*/*/C
- /private/var/folders/*/*/T

Of course, that doesn't directly imply that Time Machine is doing the same, but it is a pointer.

On my Mac some files are from /private/var/folders are included in Time Machine.  My Time Machine snapshots include just these:

- /private/var/folders/*/*/0/...

This is all largely circumstantial regarding Time Machine, but does suggest that the exclusion mechanism is more complex (or should I say hidden) than most of us expect.

Just to muddy the waters, I have to admit that the exclusions.plist file included in the root of every Time Machine (macOS 11.2) snapshot does list /private/var/folders as being excluded!

Finally, my advice is never to attempt a cleanup of system exclusions if there is any likelihood of wanting to do a full restore.

Comment: Yes I observed the stdexclusions in the bundle on my OS. What I'm hearing is that in OS 11 they have rejigged the system, but I won't be upgrading until I understand this. So you agree the contents of /private/var/folders/ should be excluded? This makes me feel not much closer to an answer for now. I'm fine not doing a full restore to be honest. It's been way too long since I cleaned house and let my OS breathe a little.

Comment: Also, just confirm for me that there is absolutely no reason to backup this stuff? I've seen threads on SE about trashing the contents (but not the folder!) as a cleanup and that's ok. Has this changed?

Comment: @RichardBirkett TM is designed to enable a full recovery and if that were your aim then don't mess with the system settings.  But if you are fine with disaster recovery by doing a clean install then you can remove most system folders - certainly /private/var/folders and much more (including /Applications?) and just keep your personal files and licences. The interesting question then is what to backup from ~/Library. And on macOS 11, TM seems to be more solid (though I have not done a full restore test) and faster.

Comment: As an aside, I use BackupLoupe to discover what has been backed up by TM.

Comment: What the heck is in private/var/folders/ that's so worth restoring? I honestly thought it was a load of temporary files made on each boot (hence why always changing). If you delete the contents they just regenerate right?

Comment: In my backups, I can see files in /private/var/folders relating to various Apple services (in particular Launch Services).  I guess that allows recovery of their state.  But, as I said, if you don't care about full recovery then exclude as much as you want.  They will be recreated with a clean install if that is your recovery method.

Comment: Ok so final question then: if I excluded /private/var/folders/ myself, and did a full recovery, would the computer function normally? I am ok with an inconvenience like losing open applications and Safari tabs.

Comment: I don't know exactly what would work and what wouldn't. From the content of files in the backup, I would expect some loss of settings relating to Apple services as a minimum.  But I am confident the computer would function. You will have to try it yourself.  Any non-standard backup and recovery needs to be tested.