# How to exclude docker files from time machine backups

Tags: macos, time-machine, docker

I don't need back up of my docker files. How do i exclude them from time machine backups

I see people mentioning /Users/david/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker folder but that does not exists on my machine.

> Docker engine version: 20.10.2 running on
> Big Sur: 11.2

**Update: Found the location**

My virtual machine appears to be here. I added it to the list of folders to be excluded. However that folder is not shown in the Time Machine UI.

> tmutil addexclusion  /Users/david/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/

Comment: Docker's not something I'm using on Big Sur - so you might need someone to help you find the folder they are dropped if the [docker GUI no longer lets you reveal them in Finder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44393211). I more generically use the storage tab of about this Mac - select manage - then use the Reduce Clutter - review files should expose any large files if docker has squirreled them away.

Comment: My Docker file appears at this location in Big Sur: ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw

Comment: I linked to a SO thread that used to show how to navigate - you should be able to test my command below and edit it / fix it or answer if you don't want to add the exclusion in the Time Machine GUI to add files to skip... Apple has a container tab in the Storage Management tool so it should show Docker container if it's large, too...

Answer (score 9):

There is a preference in Docker for this.

See screenshot from Docker Desktop 4.0.1:

[image: Docker Desktop Preferences Screen Cap]

From this [SE posting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-os-x-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup/25833#25833) and [this Docker forum posting](https://forums.docker.com/t/excluding-docker-images-from-time-machine/15985) I learned that you can run the following command to see what is being excluded from Time Machine:

```
sudo mdfind "com_apple_backup_excludeItem = 'com.apple.backupd'"
```

When I run that command in my own Mac I find the following 2 exclusions listed:

```
/Users/user/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data
/Users/user/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
```

The second directory listed there doesn't exist on my Mac but the former one includes a 64GB docker.raw file.

I am on Macos 11.6 Big Sur.

Despite all this I do find anecdotally that when I am running Docker my Time Machine backups are larger than when I am not running Docker, which makes me wonder if there are other locations that ought to be excluded but are not.

Answer (score 3):

I use the generic **addexclusion** clause of `tmutil` to make files not get backed up even if I move or copy them.

Open a Finder window to the files and a command line prompt (terminal.app is fine for this) and drag that file into the prompt after typing `tmutil addexclusion` and press enter. Here you can see me checking files on the desktop of a user named mike...

```
bmike@m1 ~ % tmutil isexcluded /Users/bmike/Desktop/Docker\ Files 
[Included]    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/bmike/Desktop/Docker Files
bmike@m1 ~ % tmutil addexclusion /Users/bmike/Desktop/Docker\ Files 
bmike@m1 ~ % tmutil isexcluded /Users/bmike/Desktop/Docker\ Files   
[Excluded]    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/bmike/Desktop/Docker Files
```