# How to Add ˜/.Trash to Time Machine Exclusions in Ventura?

Tags: time-machine, trash, apple-silicon

This topic has been covered in other questions (e.g. this one here: [On OS X, what files are excluded by rule from a Time Machine backup?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25779/on-os-x-what-files-are-excluded-by-rule-from-a-time-machine-backup) ). However, due to the significant changes in the latest versions of the Mac OS, most of it is no longer valid. As an example, a built-in list of exclusions is no longer stored in    /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/StdExclusions.plist

Allow me therefore to pose the question again.

Using the System Settings way I am not able to add the Trash folder to the exclusion list because it does not show in the home folders list:

[image]

Is there another way to add it? Or is it already excluded by default?

I have tried to run `tmutil isexcluded ~/.trash` and I get `[Excluded]    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/.trash`, but I don't know if I can trust it because if I run it for the Desktop in two different manners, I get two contradicting results:

`tmutil isexcluded ~/desktop` returns `[Included]    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/desktop`

while `tmutil isexcluded /Users/username/Desktop` returns
`[Excluded]    /System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/Desktop`

I did `sudo tmutil addexclusion -p /system/volumes/data/Users/username/.trash` but this did not add Trash in GUI:

[image]

**[EDITED Feb 26]:** I am not sure how much to trust the system. As you can see from the screenshot above, I have excluded the Desktop. However, it seems that it is still being backed up. To test it, yesterday I have placed a file directly on the desktop and another one inside a folder. Today, when browsing the Time Machine backups, I can see that they have all been backed up, regardless of the exclusion:

[image]

Comment: Case shouldn't matter, I get "excluded" for both .trash and .Trash, "included" for both "desktop" and "Desktop".

Comment: I agree, the case should not matter, but apparently in my case it does (Mac Mini M2 Pro, Ventura 13.2.1). First I thought it was the two ways to write the path, but when testing both and just changing the case of the letter D in Desktop, I get two different results. I even managed to add it twice to the GUI list by using tmutil addexclusion once with Desktop and once with desktop (as you can see in the image above)

Comment: You can even add non-existing paths via `tmutil addexclusion`, so I would focus on using `tmutil isexcluded` with paths which actually exist.

Comment: The Desktop folder exists and it can be referenced both as System/Volumes/Data/Users/username/desktop and as ~/desktop. Both are correct existing paths pointing to the same folder. However, `tmutil isexcluded` treats them as different. That is the point I was making. My apologies for not being totally clear.

Comment: Why? What make you think that ~/.Trash is backed up by TM?  Mine isn't.

Comment: Your examples for desktop are for two different folders. Do you have a `desktop` as well as `Desktop`? I only have `Desktop`.

Comment: File/dir names are not case-sensitive in the GUI (unless you formatted the volume to be case-sensitive).  But any shell command from BSD is case-sensitive unless Apple added case-folding.  That might even Apply to Apple-provided executables that contain borrowed code.

Answer (score 1):

Trash folders are not backed up by Time Machine. So there is no need to add any trash folders to the exclusions.

As you have already discovered with `tmutil isexcluded ~/.trash` the trash folder in your home directory is excluded.

But you can also look in the backup.

If your Finder shows `~/.trash` (with view hidden files enabled), you can navigate to your home folder in a TM backup.  There is no `.trash` folder in the backup.

If Finder doesn't show `~/.trash`:

1. Navigate to your backup in Finder and find your home folder;
2. Control-click and Option select Copy ... as Pathname;
3. In Terminal use `ls -lah`  and paste the path.

That will show that the trash is not present in the backup.

Comment: The last sentance is not that useful - you can't see ~/.Trash in Finder as it hodes the directory you need to use the Terminal to see it and then use the Terminal tto see it is not in the backup.

Comment: @mmmmmm Interesting point. On one of my Macs I can see ~/.trash in Finder. On my other Mac it is invisible even when view hidden files and folders is enabled (shift-command-dot). Do you know the reason for that?

Comment: what versions of macOS - this is a new feature

Comment: @mmmmmm 13.2.1 and 13.2